# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - "wlclient.properties file is missing" error during build of JavaME app

Tags: java-me, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 5.0.6.1 and I am trying to create a JavaME app that simply connects to the Worklight Server and call an adapter procedure.

I have placed the wlclient.properties file in res folder but during execution of the midlet  project I get a NullPointerException due to wlclient.properties file not found.

How to overcome this?

Comment: And your Worklight version is...?

Comment: @IdanAdar It is 5.0.6.1

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Net Beans 7.4, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-pulsar. But at the end problem is solved by using eclipse-indigo. I think the problem is with IDEs and not with my program.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you read through the training module for Java ME in Worklight 5.0.6.x?

   - [Download the training modules zip](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/wl_gs_all_modules.zip)
   - Go through 07_03_Using_Worklight_API_in_native_Java_ME_applications.pdf
2. Did you try the sample application?

   - [Download the samples zip](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/wl_gs_all_samples.zip)
   - Use the project JavaMENativeApp.zip
   - Instructions in slide #19 of the training module

Does the error also happen when using the ready-made sample project?

Comment: Have you also copied worklight-javame.jar and json4javame.jar into the lib directory of the midlet project? Could you please provide the full error details?

Comment: @ThejaswiniR yes I have copied that files

Comment: @IdanAdar thanks for providing me samples and training link, it is very useful.

Comment: @IdanAdar My question is resolved, when I have written my own answer. I have not tested the links provided by you, because I am working on J2ME for POC only.